# problem in tab bar disappear when I go from one activity to other

Tags: android

I am facing a problem in tab bar...I can show tab in my application and when I click on tab call other activity and when I go to other activity tab disappear from my window and show layout of that class but I want to show it forever in my application so what to do...? as like in iphone....is in Android it possible to show tab in every activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are jumping from one activity to another with different layout.

You need to make use of `ACTIVITYGROUP` and group all the activities to be shown under one tab.

Have a look at following link

[Android : How to have multiple activities under a single tab of TabActivity](http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity)